# Update ui from service without broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intentservice

In my app I have used `IntentService` and in it I call a webservice and parse my response. After my parsing is done I want to update the UI.

I saw that there is a way to update UI using broadcast receiver but is there any other way to update UI if I don't want to use broadcast receiver. If so then please share the link.

Answer (score 2):

You could either make a bound `Service`, or use some lib like [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

From the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> A bound service is the server in a client-server interface. A bound
>   service allows components (such as activities) to bind to the service,
>   send requests, receive responses, and even perform interprocess
>   communication (IPC). A bound service typically lives only while it
>   serves another application component and does not run in the
>   background indefinitely.

If you want to use this approach, you'll have to create a `Service` that implements the `onBind()` method. This method will return an `IBinder` that you'll also have to implement. And that `Binder` will use an `interface`, that again, you'll have to create.

Example:

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    // ...
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new MyBinder(this);
    }
}
```

**MyBinder.java**

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    private MyServiceInterface mService;

    public MyBinder(MyServiceInterface s) {
        mService = s;
    }

    public MyServiceInterface getService() {
        return mService;
    }
}
```

**MyServiceInterface.java**

```
public interface MyServiceInterface {
    int someMethod();
    boolean otherMethod();
    Object yetAnotherMethod();
}
```

For more details, you can check the docs I've linked above.

**Downside of this approach:** Regular `Service` class doesn't run on the background as `IntentService` do. So you'll also have to implement a way of running things out of the main thread.

---

And from [EventBus page](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus/blob/master/README.md):

> - simplifies the communication between components
>
>   - decouples event senders and receivers
>   - performs well with Activities, Fragments, and background threads
>   - avoids complex and error-prone dependencies and life cycle issues

To use EventBus, the best way to start is following [the documentation](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/).

So, either of those approaches seems to be a good choice for you, just as using the `BroadcastManager` (which I don't know why you can't use it).